# Check if Object contains string in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

In my `TypeScript` I have this class:

```
export class PhoneBookPerson {
    Email: string;
    Name: string;
    Phonenumber: string;
    ProfileImg: string;
    Department: string;
    JobTitle: string;
    Username: string;
}
```

I'm wondering how can I check if any of the properties contains a specific value.

```
let $SearchTerm = target.val();
function RetrievedUsers(sender: any, args: any) {
    for (let i = 0; i < users.get_count(); i++) {
        let user = users.getItemAtIndex(i);

        let person = new PhoneBookPerson();
        person.Name = user.get_loginName();
        person.Email = user.get_email();
        person.Username = user.get_loginName();
        person.JobTitle = user.get_title();
        <-- search of person contains value from $SearchTerm                        
        usermatch.push(person);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `$SearchTerm` variable? what value you want to match with wich attribute of Person?

Comment: `$SearchTerm contains any kind of value form a user input.` I would like it to see if any property in Person contains that value

Comment: Just use Object.keys(person).some(k => k.includes($SearchTerm))

Comment: I can not select includes

Comment: And why cant you "select includes"?

Comment: Because it dont show up when i type `k => k.`

Comment: what ES target are you using? Try `k.indexOf($SearchTerm) >= 0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate over object properties and check if any of them contains specified text.

Sample function to do so (I assume only string properties in object)

```
function objectContains(obj, term: string): boolean {
  for (let key in obj){
    if (obj[key].indexOf(term) != -1) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Example usage

```
if (objectContains(person, $SearchTerm)) {
  // do something
}
```